# With eslint, how to get the dependency tree for a given rule?

Tags: eslint

When using `plugins` or `extends` with ESLint, the included items can themselves further include other configurations, at times making it hard to pinpoint how a given rule made it to the final rule-set applied to a file. As an example, NPM and Yarn provide `npm ls <package>` and `yarn why <package>` to understand how a given package came to be installed.

Is there a command or other method to understand the config tree that led to a particular eslint rule being applied?

I did try the `--debug` flag, although the output was not helpful in pinpointing what caused the inclusion of a specific rule.